# How to insert SQL pivot Table to regular sql table

Tags: sql-server

How to insert `sql pivot table` to regular sql table?

I have a pivot query

```
SELECT country,
       PARTNER_ID,
       PARTNER_NAME,
       [BCS] AS BCS,
       [HPN] AS HPN,
       [ISS] AS ISS,
       [HPSD] AS HPSD
FROM   (
           SELECT COUNTRY,
                  PARTNER_ID,
                  PARTNER_NAME,
                  BU,
                  FUNDING
           FROM   ESSN_DP_CALCULATION
       ) p
       PIVOT(AVG(FUNDING)FOR BU IN ([BCS], [ISS], [HPN], [HPSD])) AS pvt
```

Which is working fine, but I  need help for inserting this values into a table called `FINAL`
which has the  same columns - `country, PARTNER_ID,PARTNER_NAME,  BCS, HPN ,ISS, HPSD`

Comment: `INSERT INTO [FINAL] SELECT ...` does not work?

Comment: Thanks .. its worked :) http://stackoverflow.com/users/569101/j0k

Comment: Please create an answer and make it as correct.